# Are there instances where spells are known to exist, but nobody knows how to cast them?

Tags: harry-potter

Are there any instances in Harry Potter, where it is theoretically known that a spell with a particular effect exists, but nobody knows how to actually cast it?

An example could be that wizards know how to cast a 'heat ray' spell and can deduce by some in-universe rules that a 'cold ray' spell must exist, but nobody can work out how to do it.

Comment: So basically, do spells exist independently of the Wizards? Do the spells exist before the knowledge of them?

Comment: A constructivist might claim that you cannot prove that the spell exists unless you can write it down.

Comment: I do not have the proper general knowledge, but this question basically begs for another one: what is the exact definition of a spell? Just the words themselves? The preparation of the wizard before casting? The "level" of the wizard? Etc... If it is just the words, it should be easy to infer. But there is some "proof" that even the quality of the wand is part of the spell (or, at least, influences the quality of the casting of the spell).

Comment: @Adamant Damn. Didn't know that's a [thing even in maths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)), Thanks.

Comment: @virolino does incantation + wand motion count? I said incantation in my original version, but it was removed in subsequent revisions.

Comment: @BCLC: You just brought to the table more words to define :) The idea is that I see 3 kinds of spells / incantations, from the POV of your question: actually known, known to exist (but only other mages know them), and assumed / inferred to exist (no known mage knows them). I guess that you ask about the third category actually, while you use the words for the second. From my limited knowledge, the incantation is the first step. No incantation = no spell. Additionally, concentration, experience, energies, helping spirits etc are needed to successfully cast the spell...

Comment: @BCLC: ... with other words, the incantation is the software (almost literally), and the others (energy, spirits...) are the hardware. The experience of the mage - the configuration files. If any of these is missing, the result and its quality cannot be guaranteed. Maybe I should have written a proper answer :)

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**

There do exist some spells in Harry Potter that only Voldemort could do such as -

> Using the highly advanced art of spell creation, Voldemort was able to create four spells/magical items unique to him alone. These included being able to fly under his own power, creating the infamous drink of despair, the rudimentary body potion, and morsmordre. Theoretically, Voldemort could have done even more which just makes him scarier.

These four spell were known to Voldemort alone and now that he is dead nobody knows how to cast them.There was the spell of Unsupported Flight that Voldemort taught to Snape but he's dead too.

Then there is his rebirth -

> Although many have tried, Tom Riddle is the only wizard to achieve complete rebirth. During his lifetime, Tom Riddle split his soul so many times that, when he was finally beaten, there was barely any humanity left. He was just a cursed soul trying to survive, which ultimately led to the scar on Harry's head.

> Due to his obsessive fear of passing away, Voldemort was able to put into action a number of contingency plans should he be stripped of his physical self. After interacting with Peter Pettigrew though the ritual, Voldemort was reborn as his physical self, becoming the first and only to do so.

So another ability that is possible but since Voldemort is dead nobody knows how to do it.

[Source](https://screenrant.com/harry-potter-voldemort-powers-potterheads/)

Comment: "Only wizard to achieve immortality" - what about Flamel and the Philosopher's Stone?

Comment: @fez I suspect the text means that he is the only one to die and come back to life preplanned.

Comment: @TheAsh - Ah, but, did Voldemort _really_ die?

Comment: @fez, edited immortality to rebirth

Comment: "Only Voldemort knows how to actually cast it" is not an answer for "nobody knows how to actually cast it"

Comment: @RalfFriedl, i further clarified that since Voldemort is dead nobody actually knows how to cast those 4 spells

Comment: Barty, and probably the other Death Eaters, can cast morsmordre. Drink of despair and rebirth ritual are not even spells. And the question doesn't seem to be about spells that are lost because nobody remembers the details, but about spells that must exist but are not (yet) discovered.

Comment: @RalfFriedl, the question reads - "Are there spells that are known to exist, but nobody knows how to cast them" , that means the spells are there but nobody knows how to cast them, their existence is true.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

Spells are invented by a wizward trying to achieve a specific effect. There are a lot of mentions throughout the books about wizards that are especially good in inventing new spells:

- Voldemort inventing several spells
- Snape inventing e.g. Sectumsempra and Levicorpus, just to mention two

Behind [this link](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Spell_creation) you can find a much longer list

And there are wizards who are not that good at all: look at Lunas mother who killed herself trying to invent a new spell

> ...she did like to experiment and one of her spells went rather badly wrong one day. I was nine."
> — Luna Lovegood, explaining her mother's death.

So if there was no wizard to invent a spell then there would be no spell.

If your question was: Are the EFFECTS of a spell that logically should exist but nobody came up with the correct spell yet: Probably... but we do not have enough information or any mention in the books for them.

But there are good examples for people looking for such spells.
Take St.-Mungo hospital: They search for a cure for Nevilles' parents and to reverse the effect of the memory charm that fired back on Gilderoy Lockhart.
Although I admit that this does not necessarily have to be a spell, it could also be a magic potion.